# Spacing within the pdf using PDFMAKE

Tags: reactjs, pdfmake

I have a table that I created in PDFMAKE with react that I would like to create spacing between that table and the text below. The text that comes after the table is placed in it and I can't make them not stick together. can anybody help me? here is the code:

const date = serviceItems.map((serviceItems) => {
{

```
    return [
      { text: serviceItems.publicId, fontSize: 9, margin: [0, 2, 0, 2] },
      { text: serviceItems.serviceCategoryTypeName, fontSize: 9, margin: [0, 2, 0, 2] },
      { text: serviceItems.serviceCategoryTypeItemName, fontSize: 9, margin: [0, 2, 0, 2] },
      { text: serviceItems.serviceCategoryTypeItemUnitQuantity, fontSize: 9, margin: [0, 2, 0, 2] },
      { text: serviceItems.serviceCategoryTypeItemUnitMeasurement, fontSize: 9, margin: [0, 2, 0, 2] },
      { text: serviceItems.status, fontSize: 9, margin: [0, 2, 0, 2] },
      { text: serviceItems.unitValue, fontSize: 9, margin: [0, 2, 0, 2] },
      { text: serviceItems.quantity, fontSize: 9, margin: [0, 2, 0, 2] },
      { text: service.total, fontSize: 9, margin: [0, 2, 0, 2] }
    ]
  }
})



const details = [{
  table: {
    headerRows: 1,
    
    widths: ['auto', 'auto', 'auto', 'auto', 'auto', 'auto', 'auto', 'auto', 'auto'],

    body: [
      [
        { text: 'A', style: 'tableExample', fontSize: 9 },
        { text: 'B', style: 'tableExample', fontSize: 9 },
        { text: 'C', style: 'tableExample', fontSize: 9 },
        { text: 'D', style: 'tableExample', fontSize: 9 },
        { text: 'E', style: 'tableExample', fontSize: 9 },
        { text: 'F', style: 'tableExample', fontSize: 9 },
        { text: 'G', style: 'tableExample', fontSize: 9 },
        { text: 'H', style: 'tableExample', fontSize: 9 },
        { text: 'I', style: 'tableExample', fontSize: 9 },
      ],
      ...date
    ]

  },
  layout: 'lightHorizontalLines\n\n\n\n\n',

}];
```